# TensorFlow - IN TF1.14 how can I make a RaggedTensor into a Tensor or how to pad it?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with TF1.14 and have the following line of code: `sparse_split_ragged = result = tf.strings.split(wo_specials, maxsplit=-1, result_type="RaggedTensor")`

Now I want to pad the result.
I thought I can either turn it into a (Dense)Tensor and than pad it, or pad it directly.
In TF2 I could have called `result.to_tensor()`

but I don't see how to do it in TF1.14.

Answer (score 1):

In `TF1.14` you also can use `to_tensor()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__) # 1.14.0

rt = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(values=[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6],
                                     row_splits=[0, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8])
astensor = rt.to_tensor()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(astensor.eval())  #[[3 1 4 1]
                            # [0 0 0 0]
                            # [5 9 2 0]
                            # [6 0 0 0]
                            # [0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad - turned out it was my bad as I was looking for the 1.14 API docs and looked at RaggedTensorValue doc by mistake [1.14 API doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.14/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/RaggedTensorValue.md). I often have a hard time when trying to understand when something was introduced to TF - see my other question at [TF @Since annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848425/tensorflow-check-since-which-api-version-a-method-is-available-as-with-javas)